# Angular component not initializing from resolve

Tags: angular, jhipster

I have a JHipster app (Angular 5 + Spring Boot 2) and I'm trying to create a new route for a model object I have (not created using the entity generator, it's just a simple model). The problem is that my component is not initializing even though I can see the Angular app is calling the correct API and getting a valid JSON response back.

Here's the model (simplified):

```
export interface IInstructor {
    id?: string;
}

export class Instructor implements IInstructor {
    constructor(
        public id?: string,
    ) {}
}
```

And the service that loads an `Instructor` object:

```
type EntityResponseType = HttpResponse<IInstructor>;
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class InstructorService {
    public resourceUrl = SERVER_API_URL + 'api/instructor';
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    get(name: string): Observable<EntityResponseType> {
        return this.http.get<IInstructor>(`${this.resourceUrl}/${name}`, { observe: 'response' });
    }
}
```

And the route + resolve:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class InstructorResolve implements Resolve<IInstructor> {
    constructor(private service: InstructorService) {}

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
        const name = route.params['name'] ? route.params['name'] : null;
        if (name) {
            return this.service.get(name).pipe(map((instructor: HttpResponse<Instructor>) => instructor.body));
        }
        return of(new Instructor());
    }
}

export const instructorRoute: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'instructor/:name',
        component: InstructorComponent,
        resolve: {
            ride: InstructorResolve
        },
        data: {
            pageTitle: 'Instructor Details'
        }
    }
];
```

And finally, the component itself and the view:

```
export class InstructorComponent implements OnInit {
    service: InstructorService;
    instructor: IInstructor;

    constructor(private instructorService: InstructorService,
                private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
                private router: Router) {
        this.service = instructorService;
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe(({ instructor }) => {
            this.instructor = instructor;
            console.log('Got instructor = ' + instructor);
        });
    }

<div id="jhi-instructor">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-lg-8">
            <hr/>
            <h2>Instructor Details</h2>
            <div *ngIf="instructor !== null">
                <h2>{{instructor.id}}</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I navigate to `/instructor/somename` I can see in the Chrome debugger that is makes the XHR call to the spring boot app, and it gets a valid JSON payload back. But inside `InstructorComponent`, the `instructor` variable is never set. I see the console message from `ngOnInit`, but the object being returned from the `activatedRoute` is null:

```
Got instructor = undefined instructor.component.ts:27:12
ERROR TypeError: "_co.instructor is undefined"
    View_InstructorComponent_1 InstructorComponent.html:1
```

This is a pattern I've followed for other parts of the app (and basically re-used from auto generated JHipster code) and it's worked fine, so I'm not sure what I'm missing.

**Update**

As I suspected, it was human error. I had copied the route from another component and did not change the resolve value (it was using *ride* instead of *instructor*). Many thanks for the suggestions!

```
resolve: {
    instructor: InstructorResolve
},
```

Comment: Could you try this.activatedRoute.snapshot.data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess a small correction made as follows can get you the desired data in the component.

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: 'instructor/:name',
    component: InstructorComponent,
    resolve: {
        ride: InstructorResolve
    },
    data: {
        pageTitle: 'Instructor Details'
    }
}]
```

And in the component, make the changes as follows.

```
export class InstructorComponent implements OnInit {
  service: InstructorService;
  instructor: IInstructor;

  constructor(private instructorService: InstructorService,
              private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
              private router: Router) {
      this.instructor = this.route.snapshot.data["ride"];
      this.service = instructorService;
  }

}
```

You need to retrieve data by using the same key used for resolving at the routing part, in the component so as to get the resolved data from the route.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Marking this as accepted due to the extra verbiage about the key which ultimately led me to the the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try to the following code

```
export class InstructorComponent implements OnInit {
  service: InstructorService;
  instructor: IInstructor;

  constructor(private instructorService: InstructorService,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router) {
    this.service = instructorService;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.snapshot.data("ride").subscribe(({ instructor }) => {
      this.instructor = instructor;
      console.log('Got instructor = ' + instructor);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it was indeed an issue of having copied the route from another component and not changing the key name.